# My friend sent me a screenshot of a transaction hash, but when I search for it I find divergent data. What happened?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, ether, etherscan, blocks

This is the transaction hash:

[0x90e923ee01d9dfeb95ee176819eeec67d247fc6cb009c8cdc4d8ae1939e5ecc6](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x90e923ee01d9dfeb95ee176819eeec67d247fc6cb009c8cdc4d8ae1939e5ecc6)

And this is the screenshot my friend sent me:

[image: Txid]

If you check the hash in Etherscan, some informations converge with the screenshot - block, number of confirmations and sender address - but other info are divergent - receiver address, date and amount sent. What could have happened?

Answer (score 8):

Your friend simply edited the HTML and changed the `TimeStamp`, `To`, and `Value` on that page.

You can tell this because all of the other stats on the page are correct, with the exception of the items noted above. *This includes* the `Block`. You know that the image has been edited because the `Block` and the `timestamp` simply do not match (nor are they even close). The `Block` parameter is the true parameter, [given the current state of the network](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x90e923ee01d9dfeb95ee176819eeec67d247fc6cb009c8cdc4d8ae1939e5ecc6). This tx hash also does not exist on any other network.

Comment: Well that's a massive red flag.